# Setting the token for API client generated instances in an Angular application

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular-2+, reactive-programming

I am developing an Angular application who also consumes an external REST API. I am also trying the [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) using a TypeScript template.

The OK path is the following:

- call a method that requires a username + password and get a token
- set the token on a configuration object
- update the generated instance API client with that configuration (which should also receive a base path)
- use the instance API client to call a method

**`DataLakeSecurityClientCustomizationService`**

This takes care of initializing the API clients and setting the token when this is refreshed.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class DataLakeSecurityClientCustomizationService {

    constructor(
        private readonly defaultService: DefaultService,
        private readonly securityTagsService: SecurityTagsService,
        /* other generated API client service instances will be here */) {
    }

    init() {
        this.defaultService.configuration.basePath = environment.dataLakeSecurityApiBasePath;
        this.securityTagsService.configuration.basePath = environment.dataLakeSecurityApiBasePath;
    }

    setToken(token: string) {
        this.securityTagsService.configuration.accessToken = token;
        // all other used services will get the token here
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  private initDataLakeExtAuth() {
    this.dataLakeCustService.init();

    // trying to get a token ASAP to use for subsequent calls
    this.store.dispatch(RequestNewTokenAction());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initDataLakeExtAuth();
  }
```

**Authentication effect**

This handles getting the token which is happening outside of reducer's pure functions. I am using ngrx/store framework (Angular 8 version).

```
@Injectable()
export class DataLakeExtAuthEffects {

    constructor(
        private readonly actions$: Actions,
        private readonly dataLakeExtAuthService: DataLakeExtAuthService,
        private readonly store: Store<AppState>,
        private readonly logger: LoggingService,
        private readonly dataLakeSecurityClientCustomizationService: DataLakeSecurityClientCustomizationService
    ) { }

    getNewToken$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(RequestNewTokenAction),
        switchMap(_ => {
            this.store.dispatch(LoadingStartedAction({ message: "Performing security level authentication ..."}));

            return this.dataLakeExtAuthService.getLoginToken().pipe(
                tap(() => this.store.dispatch(LoadingEndedAction())),
                catchError(err => {
                    this.store.dispatch(LoadingEndedAction());
                    this.logger.logErrorMessage("Error getting a Data Lake Security View token: " + err);

                    this.store.dispatch(NewTokenLoadCancelledAction());
                    return of<string>();
                }));
            }),
        map((token: string) => {
            this.dataLakeSecurityClientCustomizationService.setToken(token);

            return NewTokenLoadedAction({token});
        }))
    );
}
```

#### The authentication service for the external REST API

```
@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class DataLakeExtAuthService {

    credentials = DataLakeCredentials;

    constructor(private readonly defaultService: DefaultService,
                private readonly logger: LoggingService) {
    }

    getLoginToken(): Observable<string> {
        const token$ = this.defaultService.loginTokenPost(this.credentials.username, this.credentials.password)
            .pipe(
                map((payload: { access_token: string }) => payload.access_token),
                tap((token: string) => {
                    this.logger.logTrace("Received token: ", token);
                })
            );
        return token$;
    }
}
```

`DefaultService` is an automatically generated TypeScript class that actually performs the API call.

I am looking for improvement suggestions for this pattern I am using. Also, I cannot control what code is generated through the OpenAPI generator.